# MVC Project published in third party hosting - throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, publish

I created an App in VS 2017. It has a SQL Database (Entity Framework connected) and other MVC components. in the local IIS it works without any trouble.
Assume the Project is in folder (of local machine) : `MVCPrj`

I have a website and it has a particular folder, in which there is a Web Forms project and that runs in the site without any trouble as well.
Assume the Project is in Folder : `BaseFolderInMySite\WebFormsPrj`

The following works without any trouble

```
http://www.mySite/WebFormsPrj/default.aspx
```

For testing purposes, I need to create a separate folder inside `BaseFolderInMySite` and I want to place the MVC project inside it.

I created that folder and published the app. I can see the files properly placed in the directory.  But that site gives an error page. The old one works.

If I summarize:
The Webforms app in `BaseFolderInMySite\WebFormsPrj` works for `http://www.mySite/WebFormsPrj/default.aspx`

The MVC app in `BaseFolderInMySite\MVCPrj` **doesn't** works for `http://www.mySite/MVCPrj`

Here is the error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ9AA.png)

Since it is saying the web,config file has the issue, I checked it. It is the line with

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

I googled, checked thoroughly in SO and tried to get it fixed by various means and failed.
I removed the `<system.web>` thinking that it conflicts with the main app, which is running.
Changed the mode to Windows, Forms, ... no luck.

My question is how do I fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [web.config allowDefinition=MachineToApplication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307112/web-config-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-error)

Comment: @Gusman, That is for a web forms project. my web forms is working ok. my problem is with the MVC Project in the same base directory as the web forms

Comment: Your problem is that you have a `web.config` somewhere that it's not the root nor a virtual directory and it includes directives that can only be placed on the root `web.config`. That's what that answer explains.

Comment: Did you try just the MVC project only?

Comment: @Gusman, I have web.config files already in base folder and inside the webforms project folder. But this project is separate.

Comment: Is separate but you haven't placed it in a virtual directory, so some directives can't be specified in it's web.config.

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage, No, it is quite a bit tedious and risky. the one in web forms is working. I don't want to disrupt it

Comment: @Gusman, sorry, i'm not getting you. i cannot create any virtual directory in the hosting site. I created a regular folder by log-in using ftp

Comment: Then you can't change authentication mode, it's set at application level, in the root web.config. In order to specify a different authentication mode you must create a different application (another site) or a virtual directory.

Comment: @Gusman, Is there a way to have both projects with one web.config

Comment: @Gusman,
I renamed the web.config in the base folder. Still the Web Forms one working, but not the  MVC one